# How can I load directory after run local server in terminal?

Tags: php, terminal, localhost

when I write `cd project` in my terminal then I get this line:

```
MacBook-Pro:project work$
```

I run my local server like this

```
MacBook-Pro:project work$ php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public
```

After that I see this:

```
PHP 7.2.6 Development Server started at Tue May 29 10:45:40 2018
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000
Document root is /Users/work/project/public
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

But then I want to go back to my project folder `MacBook-Pro:project work$` but when I write `cd` oder `cd project` nothing happens. Only when I press Ctr-C then this line `MacBook-Pro:project work$`appears again. Do I really have to quit my server to go into my project folder?

Comment: why don You just open next terminal.

Comment: @Pyton I am new in terminal. And I thought this is some kind of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public &
```

in your terminal. `&` will set the task to be run in the background. Any output the command produces will be output to your terminal though.

To stop the command (`Ctrl-C` in this case) you first need to `fg` in your terminal to get it to the foreground, then `Ctrl-C` to quit.

Comment: Ah ok, did not know this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the server in the foreground, then it is responsible for handling all input. You don't have direct access to the shell.

If you don't want that, then open another terminal, or run the server in the background, or use a multiplexer like `screen` or `tmux`.

Comment: How do I run the server in the background?